# How to deploy only a bug-fixed class on WildFly

Tags: jboss, wildfly, wildfly-11

Does anyone know the best way to deploy only a bug-fixed class if a bug is found in a Web application running on WildFly and it is fixed?

If using Tomcat instead of WildFly, I will deploy the class in webapps/my-app/classes/ with package directories in order to minimize an influential range of the changes.

What would you do if you are using WildFly?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the 'same' things in wildfly with deployments in the deployments folder, but you can also use overlays to 'replace' a class or file with an overlay. Using exploded-deployments you can also replace a class file in a jar / war / ear. please note that you might need to redeploy the applications after that.

Comment: Do you mean if using standalone mode and fixed class is deployed in `standalone/deployments/classes/package/dir/`, then it will be reloaded (overrode the existing class) after restart?

Comment: Yes or after issuing a redeploy command either via jboss-cli or using a .dodeploy. If you deploy your application with a packaged archive then you should take a look at overlays and/or exploded deployments (but for the latest you need a more up to date wildfly). Also one solution could be the use of the git support in WildFly and updating the git repo with the updated application binaries and a restart of the server.